# Division in Haskell doesn't work due to wrong type

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get the sum of all elements in a list, what works so far. And I have the amount of elements. I want to divide the sum by the amount to get the average of all elements in this list. And the division gives me an error back I can't fix.
My code:

```
module HA

where

import FPH
import Data.List.Split
import Data.Char
import qualified Data.Text hiding (length)

s1 = splitOn " " sonnet18
s2 = splitOn " " sonnet73

countSubStrs str sub = length $ Data.Text.breakOnAll (Data.Text.pack sub) (Data.Text.pack str)

task :: IO ()
task = do
    let wordLengths = map length
    let wl1 = wordLengths s1
    let wl2 = wordLengths s2
    let getsum1 = sum wl1
    let ln [] = 0
    let ln (x:xs) =1 + ln xs
    let average = wl1 `quot` getsum1
    print average
```

The error:

```
Couldn't match expected type '[Int]' with actual type 'Int'
In the second argument of `quot´, namely `getsum1´
In the expression: wl1 `quot´ getsum1
In an equation for `average´: average = wl1 `quot´ getsum1
```

Comment: What is `s1` and `s2` ?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. s1 and s2 are two sonnets of the type list. I converted a string of the text with SplitOn to lists.

Comment: Also please provide the full error message. This way we can not see where the error occurs.

Comment: You just removed the actual code of your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't done yet.

Comment: The problem is, that `wordLengths` returns a list of the word lengths instead of one number. Furthermore you should also provide the definitions of `sonnet1/2` and remove the import of `FPH`.

Comment: Beware that `let ln [] = ... ; let ln (x:xs) = ...` defines `ln` only according to the second equation! The first one is shadowed (`-Wall` should warn you about that, turn it on!). You should use both equations inside the same let (remove the second `let` and indent the second `ln` under the first one).

Comment: `ln` is both unused and (more or less) the same as `sum`; why are you defining it in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by walking through some types:

```
task :: IO ()
task = do
    let wordLengths = map length -- (:: [[Char]] -> [Int]) 
    let wl1 = wordLengths s1     -- (:: [Int])
    let wl2 = wordLengths s2     -- (:: [Int])
    let getsum1 = sum wl1        -- (:: Int)
    let ln [] = 0
    let ln (x:xs) =1 + ln xs
    let average = wl1 `quot` getsum1
    print average
```

The terms we should be looking at here are `wl1` and `getsum1`, since our error is occurring on the operation involving them. First, the function `quot`:

```
ghci>> :t quot
Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

So we can apply it to two arguments that are members of the typeclass `Integral`. Do both are arguments satisfy that constraint? We said `getsum1` had type `Int` above, so we're good there. `wl1`, on the other hand, has type `[Int]`. There's our problem.

How should we go about fixing this, based on what you've outlined? We want to divide the sum of lengths by the number of items in the list (presumably to get the average length of words from our original `[[Char]]`). So we'll want do divide `getsum1` by `length wl1` (depending on what sort of format you expect for the result, there are several ways you could do this).